# Logging into Devise from a Rake Task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rake

(Edit: this code actually works, the error was in my original code, which had an incorrect email address!)

I've figured out how to log into Devise from the console, however when I attempt to do the same from a rake task it gives me 401 unauthorised when posting to sign in. This is my rake task. (These same steps work in the console).

```
task :get_home => :environment do
  app = ActionDispatch::Integration::Session.new Rails.application
  app.get '/users/sign_in'
  p csrf_token = app.session[:_csrf_token]

  app.post '/users/sign_in',{:authenticity_token => csrf_token, :user => {:email => "example@example.com", :password => "password"}}
  app.get ''

  p csrf_token = app.session[:_csrf_token]
  app.get '/users'

  File.open("users", "w+") do |f|
    f.write(app.response.body)
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you seeing any useful information in development.log? Are the parameters at the start of the Post request showing what you expect?

Answer (score 2):

User error, I typed in the .con for the email instead of .com.
I must be tired, i double and triple checked the parameters and never noticed this... until an hour later. (i changed the actual email in my post, but in my code it was incorrect)

Answer (score 0):

For newer versions of Rails this still needs parameters specified. This line will toss an error `ArgumentError: unknown keywords: authenticity_token, user`:

```
app.post '/users/sign_in',{:authenticity_token => csrf_token, :user => {:email => "example@example.com", :password => "password"}}
```

To rectify it just add parameters:

```
app.post '/users/sign_in',{:params => {:authenticity_token => csrf_token, :user => {:email => "example@example.com", :password => "password"}}}
```